# pass data between two UITableView with custom cell

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview

I'm going to pass data from a UITableViewController to another UITableViewController. These two UITableViewController have custom cell in it.
When I pass the data by segue, I can't get the data from sourceViewController as it says that there's no member of the label I built in the Custom UITableViewCell controller.

[image: I link the 2 UITableViewController by push segue]

**Main Problem that find no member in menuController. Do I need to inherit or delegate the custom cell to menuController or push it?**

[image: Here is the main problem that find no member in menuController]

Here is the code of ordersController:

```
import UIKit
struct Order { 
   var tilte:String 
   var price:String 
   var quantity:String
}

class ordersController: UITableViewController {
var orders = Array<Order>()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

//handle exit from Cancel back of menuController
@IBAction func cancelBack(segue: UIStoryboardSegue){
}

//handle exit from Done back of menuController
@IBAction func doneBack(segue: UIStoryboardSegue){
    print("Done and Back")

    //let source = segue.sourceViewController as! newMenu
    //let quantity = source.burgerQuan.text

}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.orders.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("orderedItem", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ordersCustomCell

    let order:Order = self.orders[indexPath.row]
    cell.ordersName.text = orders[indexPath.row].title
    cell.ordersPrice.text = orders[indexPath.row].price
    cell.ordersQuantity.text = orders[indexPath.row].quantity

    return cell
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
}
```

Here is code of Custom Cell of ordersController:

```
class ordersCustomCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var ordersName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var ordersPrice: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var ordersQuantity: UILabel! 

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}
```

Here is the code of menuController:

```
class menuController: UITableViewController {

var items:[String] = ["Hamburger","French Fries", "Coffee", "Lemon Tea"]
var price:[String] = ["$29", "$13", "$25", "$8"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("menuItem", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! menuCustomCell

    cell.menuName.text = self.items[indexPath.row]
    cell.menuPrice.text = self.price[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
}
```

And here is code of custom cell of menuController:

```
class menuCustomCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var menuName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var menuPrice: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var menuQuantity: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var stepper: UIStepper!

@IBAction func stepperValueChanged(sender: UIStepper) {
    menuQuantity.text = Int(sender.value).description
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}
}
```

How can I do this? --> When the Add button in Orders is clicked, it shows the Menu. User click the stepper to select the quantity. Then, data pass back to Orders when user click Done. The items which quantity is not 0 will be shown on the list on Orders.

Answer (score 0):

Your `menuController` class does not that that variable `menuName`, thats why it cannot find it.

All you have is `items` and `price` in that view controller.

You have `menuName` within your custom cell. That is different from the viewController you are pushing too.

Comment: so I need to assign those Outlets in both menuController and menuCustomCell?

Comment: your using a tableview, so cellForRowAtIndexPath will be populating the cells. Which is generally an array of items. If you have static cells - then you don't need to subclass them - you can just create outlets directly to the View Controller.